# Alternatives to Maplex Labeling Engine for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, cartography, software-recommendations, basic-license-level

I am running ArcGIS 10 (ArcView) with the standard labeling engine. I am very familiar with Maplex and have used it in the past but it still lacked the "feature-linked" functionality given the type of license I use. (Arc Info - Maplex combination was quite good)
Still, I found Maplex to be better than the built-in labeling engine but not stellar. Decent label masking for elevation contours and orienting labels up-slope, etc. are still difficult if not impossible to acheive even with maplex. 
Area there any good alternatives?

Comment: http://www.maptext.com/Label-EZ.shtml (never used it as have ArcInfo with Maplex) I would like to see improvements in Maplex by version ArcGIS 10.2, have given ESRI many hours of product improvement they just don't have the resources to improve the Carto aspects that makes the maps cleaner and more useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes **Maperitive** is a good (though young) Open Source verison of Maplex capabilities

[works more closely to the orignal standalone Maplex software which works with shapefiles and controls layers as well as text placement]

http://maperitive.net/docs/manual/

Text Rendering
http://maperitive.net/docs/manual/Properties/Text.html

Google Group:
http://groups.google.co.uk/group/maperitive/topics?gvc=1